# How in IIB to make a soap request and get a response?

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

There is a WSDL service http://web.cse.ru/1c/ws/Web1C.1cws?wsdl How to make a correct request using the ibm integration bus and get a response when calling the ping method. I do the following for the test: I added a static library with this WSDL file, then an HTTP Input Node, then I tried to do a Mapping Node, then a SOAP request NODE, in which this WSDL is specified. I did everything in the debag mod with break points to see what answers are coming. But with any of my actions, I can’t achieve my goal in any way: to make a request to this soap service in order to simply get a response from the ping function. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.
Made before the esql compute query and added the called function
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.ns:Ping = '';
and got what I wanted!